# Piecewise cases ; align the x of each condition

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I need to notate this function:

```
\begin{align*}
  f(x)=\begin{cases} 
    -1,-\pi<x<0 \\
    1,0<x<\pi
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

How can I get the two conditions to align by the x? Simply putting an ampersand before the x doesn't work (that causes strange space from the lower bound to the x.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alignedat`; I also add another form, where adding “for” seems to make the alignment unnecessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
-1, & \quad & -\pi & < x < 0   \\
 1, & \quad &    0 & < x < \pi
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{for $-\pi < x < 0$} \\
 1, & \text{for $0 < x < \pi$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the equation environment instead of align? Please can you have a look at [my follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392501/problems-aligning-piecewise-cases-with-other-functions)

Comment: @theonlygusti For a single equation it's better to use `equation`; `align` is for multiline displays (`cases` isn't).

Comment: what about the equation environment vs `$$`?

Comment: @theonlygusti `$$` should never be used in LaTeX. See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 0):

I propose this, with `empheq` and `alignat*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={f(x)=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat*=3}
-1, &\quad & \text{if} &~ & -\pi & < x < 0 \\
 1, & & \text{if}& & 0 & < x < \pi
 \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `\phantom` over`lap`ping to achieve the same result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases} 
              -1, &                     -\pi < x < 0 \\
    \phantom{-}1, & \phantom{-\pi}\llap{$0$} < x < \pi
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```